# Linear regression with the addition of a Euclidean norm penalty

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-regression

Define
$$
\begin{align*}
X &:= \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 5 & 0 & 2\\
-7 & 0 & -3 & 0\\
0 & 7 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}\\
y &:= \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3\\
4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$

Consider the unique function $f:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(\beta) = \|y - X\beta\|^2$ for every $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^4$ ($\|\cdots\|$ being the Euclidean norm).

[It can be shown](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ordinary_least_squares&oldid=1024751917#Matrix/vector_formulation) that $f$ has a global minimum that is attained at $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ and only there.

What happens to the minimizing vector and to the minimum value, if we replace $f$ by the unique function $p:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $p(\beta) = f(\beta)+\|\beta\|^2$ for every $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: The solution changes. The additional terms reduces the domain for feasible $\beta's$. It is similar to having an optimization problem with restrictions (where one uses Lagrange multipliers)

Comment: @OliverDiaz: Thanks. However there are no Lagrange multipliers corresponding to the question of minimizing $p$, since there are no constraints.

Comment: I know there are no L.M. but that is why I said similar. Notice that you could have the objective function $f_\lambda(\beta)=\|y- X\beta\|^2_2+\lambda\|\beta\|^2_2$ and use $\lambda$ as a parameter to control for bias and variance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can easily find a derivative of $p$:
$$
\nabla p(\beta) = 2(-X)^\top (y-X \beta) + 2\beta = -2X^\top y + (2\mathrm{Id}+2X^\top X)\beta \overset{!}{=} 0 \iff \boldsymbol{\beta} = (\mathrm{Id}+ X^\top X)^{-1}(X^\top y)
$$

To verify that this is indeed a minimizer, we observe that the hessian $Hp(\beta) = 2(\mathrm{Id} + X^\top X)$ is positive definite.

So the identity matrix squeezes in to account for the penalty $\lVert \beta \rVert^2$.

Maybe you can also use $QR$-decompostion to prove this...